# how to find all shared regions between two images

Tags: image-processing

I've been trying to find something that automatically finds all shared regions between two images, explicitly *not* based on pixel-matching or differencing, and I'm basically coming up with nothing after a fair bit of searching.

Say I have the following two images, in this case, website screenshots. The first the "baseline":

[image]

and the second very similar but with some modified CSS so entire blocks have been moved around. No text content changes, no box dimension changes, just some elements repositioned:

[image]

In this case (but also in literally every other case where two images where one is a derivative of the other are to be compared) their pixel diff is effectively useless for seeing what changed:

[image]

In fact, even if we apply some simple diff exaggeration, the result is *still* fairly useless because we're still looking at pixel diffs, instead of diffs based on what *changed*, so we won't (in any way) be looking at the actual modifications to the visual information:

[image]

So this is like comparing two books and then deciding the books are different based on how many values for `n` we can find for which `book1.letters[n] != book2.letters[n]`...

So, what I'm looking for is a way to compute regions of similarity, showing which parts of the two images encode the same information, but not necessarily in the same bounding boxes.

For instance, in the above two images, almost all the data is the same, just with some parts relocated. The only true difference is that there's mystery whitespace.

With similar regions color coded:

[image]

and the correspondence:

[image]

I can't find a single tool to do this, and I can't even find tutorials that allow for implementation of this using opencv or similar technologies. Maybe I'm looking for the wrong terms, maybe no one actually ever wrote an image comparison tool for this (which seems beyond belief?), so at the risk of this being off topic: I [searched and researched](/help/how-to-ask) as much as I can, here. What are my options if I need this as a tool that can be run as part of a normal (open source) tool chain for QA/testing? (so: not some expensive plugin to equally expensive commercial software).

Comment: I did something similar ages ago so maybe have a look there... https://stackoverflow.com/a/27342865/2836621

Comment: This looks like a very complex problem, you need to do several tasks before achieving that result: you need to bound your image in segmented regions and compare each one of them in order to establish which of them are the same and then you need to establish if there are located in the same place or are misplaced

Comment: @MarkSetchell, that's really neat

Comment: Of course it's a complex problem @Nightmerker. If it wasn't, there would be plenty of implementations available already. The complex problems are the ones that actually help solve real problems when figured out (in this case, actually helping teams do styling and presentation QA in an efficient manner).

Comment: @Mark I was hoping to avoid the "sliding puzzle" solution, where you chop up one of the images and then try to fit the pieces in the other. I was thinking of a SIFT map for both and then doing a subgraph fit by taking random seeds in one and finding the maximum fit as you grow the graph you're trying to fit, so that you're not "sliding" so much as "subset matching using image features that you know are valid anchors".

Comment: A nice challenge we have here, I'll be waiting for the solution in here as I'll also try to find it too.

Comment: A successful clustering of region in the initial process will help a lot . But what if some of the contents are different ? i.e the order of the tags are slightly different, are they considered the same ?

Comment: "not based on pixel-matching or differencing" is a little nonsensical. You'll have to compare the pixels somehow.

Comment: I see you've not heard of FFT or PCA matching. This problem is not actually about "matching pixels", but is really about "matching image data", so while pixels are the obvious starting point when you're a human being, using computers we can typically do way better matching by moving off of pixels as soon as possible and instead matching on SIFT feature graphs, FFT profiles, multi segment PCA, etc, with pixel verification as a last optional step if you need that extra security.

Comment: @yapws87 indeed, that's part of it. The typical solution even in pixel matchers is to offer a control parameter that you can use to indicate the maximum acceptable mismatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question: [opencv](https://opencv.org/) ([for python](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/)) paired with [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/) can pretty much get us there in two steps.

1. perform an [SSIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_similarity) comparison between the two images, capturing the various differences in bbox contours relative to the second image
2. for each contour in the second image, perform [template matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_matching) with respect to the first image, which tells us if a diff contour is a "change" or a "translation".

In code, assuming two images `imageA` and `imageB`, with the same dimensions:

```python
import cv2
import imutils
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity

# ...a bunch of functions will be going here...

diffs = compare(imageA, imageB, gray(imageA), gray(imageB), [])

if len(diffs) > 0:
    highlight_diffs(imageA, imageB, diffs)

else:
    print("no differences detected")
```

with:

```python
def gray(img):
    return cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

def compare(or1, or2, im1, img2, diffs):
    (score, diff) = structural_similarity(im1, img2, full=True)
    diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")

    thresh = cv2.threshold(diff, 0, 255,
        cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    contours = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(),
        cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours = imutils.grab_contours(contours)

    # aggregate the contours, throwing away duplicates
    for c in contours:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        region = [x, y, x + w, y + h]
        try:
            diffs.index(region)
        except ValueError:
            diffs.append(region)

    return diffs
```

Now, `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL` is supposed to only yield "External contours", e.g. if there's diffs *inside* other diffs (say a box's border color changed, and some text inside the box also changed), it should just yield one box, being the outer ("external") box.

Except that's not what it does, so I wrote a dumb function that naively weeds inner boxes:

```python
def filter_diffs(diffs):
    def not_contained(e, diffs):
        for t in diffs:
            if e[0] > t[0] and e[2] < t[2] and e[1] > t[1] and e[3] < t[3]:
                return False
        return True

    return [e for e in diffs if not_contained(e, diffs)]
```

which then gets used in the function that highlights the differences using color rectangles.

```python
RED = (0,0,255)

def highlight_diffs(a, b, diffs):
    diffed = b.copy()

    for area in filter_diffs(diffs):
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = area
        cv2.rectangle(diffed, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), RED, 2)

    cv2.imshow("Diffed", diffed)
```

This gets us the first part. Taking a screenshot of Stackoverflow, and then another screenshot after moving the left advertisement down, and recoloring the `--yellow-100` CSS variable:

[image]

This finds five diffs, but two of them aren't really "diffs" in the sense that it's new or removed content, but rather it's the result of "we moved a thing down".

So, let's add in the template matching:

```python
def highlight_diffs(a, b, diffs):
    diffed = b.copy()

    for area in filter_diffs(diffs):
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = area

        # is this a relocation, or an addition/deletion?
        org = find_in_original(a, b, area)
        if org is not None:
            cv2.rectangle(a, (org[0], org[1]), (org[2], org[3]), BLUE, 2)
            cv2.rectangle(diffed, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), BLUE, 2)
        else:
            cv2.rectangle(diffed, (x1+2, y1+2), (x2-2, y2-2), GREEN, 1)
            cv2.rectangle(diffed, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), RED, 2)

    cv2.imshow("Original", a)
    cv2.imshow("Diffed", diffed)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

With the following code for the template matching, with an *incredibly strict* threshold for "is the match we found actually good":

```python
def find_in_original(a, b, area):
    crop = b[area[1]:area[3], area[0]:area[2]]
    result = cv2.matchTemplate(crop, a, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

    (minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
    (startX, startY) = maxLoc
    endX = startX + (area[2] - area[0])
    endY = startY + (area[3] - area[1])
    ocrop = a[startY:endY, startX:endX]

    # this basically needs to be a near-perfect match
    # for us to consider it a "moved" region rather than
    # a genuine difference between A and B.
    if structural_similarity(gray(ocrop), gray(crop)) >= 0.99:
        return [startX, startY, endX, endY]
```

We can now compare the original and modified image, and see that the ad got moved in the modified image, rather than being "new content", and we can see where it can be found in the original:

[image]
[image]

And that's it, we have a visual diff that actually tells us something useful about the changes, rather than telling us which pixel happens to be a different colour.

We could bring down the template matching threshold down a little to, say, 0.95, in which case the whitespace box would also end up matched to the original image, but because it's just whitespace it'll get matched to something mostly meaningless (in this particular case, it'll match it to the whitespace in the lower right of the original).

Of course, quality of life improvements would be to cycle through colours so that various moved parts can all be related to each other by their shared colour, but that's the kind of thing that anyone can probably tack on top of this code themselves.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a suggestion for the initial region clustering.

First we subtract the 2 images to find out region that is different. Then we resize it to smaller scale for faster speed and easier clustering.

[image]

Then we run morphological close operation to cluster all nearby objects together.

[image]

Threshold the result to obtain the strong signals

[image]

Run connected component analysis to get all the bounding boxes.

[image]

Then check for all the box intersections and unionize them. In my case, i just redrew all the bounding boxes in solid mode and re-analyze the component to obtain regions

[image]

Once we have this, we can run the same process on the second image and cross match each of the region extracted using a simple cross correlation matching method or any other fancy method for matching. In this case, a simple width and height matching of between regions will do as well.

Here is the code i made. I hope it helps.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


# Function to fill all the bounding box
def fill_rects(image, stats):

    for i,stat in enumerate(stats):
        if i > 0:
            p1 = (stat[0],stat[1])
            p2 = (stat[0] + stat[2],stat[1] + stat[3])
            cv2.rectangle(image,p1,p2,255,-1)


# Load image file
img1 = cv2.imread('img1.jpg',0)
img2 = cv2.imread('img2.jpg',0)

# Subtract the 2 image to get the difference region
img3 = cv2.subtract(img1,img2)

# Make it smaller to speed up everything and easier to cluster
small_img = cv2.resize(img3,(0,0),fx = 0.25, fy = 0.25)


# Morphological close process to cluster nearby objects
fat_img = cv2.dilate(small_img, None,iterations = 3)
fat_img = cv2.erode(fat_img, None,iterations = 3)

fat_img = cv2.dilate(fat_img, None,iterations = 3)
fat_img = cv2.erode(fat_img, None,iterations = 3)

# Threshold strong signals
_, bin_img = cv2.threshold(fat_img,20,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Analyse connected components
num_labels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(bin_img)

# Cluster all the intersected bounding box together
rsmall, csmall = np.shape(small_img)
new_img1 = np.zeros((rsmall, csmall), dtype=np.uint8)

fill_rects(new_img1,stats)


# Analyse New connected components to get final regions
num_labels_new, labels_new, stats_new, centroids_new = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(new_img1)


labels_disp = np.uint8(200*labels/np.max(labels)) + 50
labels_disp2 = np.uint8(200*labels_new/np.max(labels_new)) + 50



cv2.imshow('diff',img3)
cv2.imshow('small_img',small_img)
cv2.imshow('fat_img',fat_img)
cv2.imshow('bin_img',bin_img)
cv2.imshow("labels",labels_disp)
cv2.imshow("labels_disp2",labels_disp2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: While an efficient way to find "diff regions", and certainly worth an upvote, this approach still runs into the same problem as standard pixel matching: it doesn't highlight actual differences between the two images in terms of visual data location, it just more efficiently highlights regions where the pixels differ. Think of text diffing: if I add the letter "a" at the start of a text file, the diff is "the letter a, at the start", not "every single letter in the text file has changed". We want the former, but this approach is the image equivalent of the latter still.

Comment: (to confirm that, imagine someone accidentally set `body { padding-top: 10em; }` instead of `body { padding-top: 10px; }`. That first step pixel diff will yield an initial diff that is effectively _the entire page_ even though nothing has changed: we just have additional white space up top. The actual diff we should be finding is that whitespace bounding box)

Comment: I guess i misunderstood your intention the first time. However, after we find the different region and relocated them to match the initial image, we can perform again subtraction between the 2 image and obtain the white region difference you are looking for.

Comment: As for the addition of 'a' to a start of a text, it would be a super difficult problem if that 'a' induce a change of paragraph of the entire text which essentially disables any global visual representations. The only way i can think of is to approach the text word by word.....

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. I want an image diff for image data that works the same as a text diff works for text: showing additions/removals/relocations instead of comparing individual pixels at pixel coordinates (which is like comparing text by looking at array positions instead of... you know... _the text_). In image context, if some text in an image has an `a` added that reflowed the entire paragraph it was in (but not subsequent paragraphs, of course; those would just be moved down) then of course a visual diff should show that entire paragraph as being entirely different, because it is.

Comment: Then i feel the region relocation and subtraction should achieve your goals. Relocation of region is used to arrange the content of the 2 images to be as similar as possible(this process shows relocation). Then the subtraction between the transformed image should reveal the addition and removal changes you are looking for.

Comment: The other parameter you need to consider is how detail of a change you want.  A super detailed changes will require the use of the original image resolution while for a rough region changes, you should shrink the image to cluster the information together. It is after-all visual cue. A complex structure should combine both to form a pyramidal search scheme.

Comment: Naturally, but that's what parameter tweaking is for. Initial seed size, similarity metric, growth tolerance, etc. can all be set parametric with some sane-but-hardly-universal values. I really am primarily concerned with find even just _anything_ that does real image diffing, even if all the parameterizing is left as an exercise for the repo-cloner.

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion:**

The problem can be much eased if you are able to segment out the blue sentences, which can be achieved by morphological dilation followed by binarization. If the dilation is strong enough that all characters come in contact (though distinct rows of text stay apart), connected components labeling can extract hole lines.

Now you have bounding boxes and the number of positions to be tried is much reduced.

Also look at the diff algorithm, which can be relevant for sequential text. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff

[image]

Comment: What "blue sentences" would you be referring to?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Er, can't make it clearer. They are sentences and they are blue.

Comment: And I have no idea what we're talking about: I am not trying to diff Stackoverflow, so I don't care about "blue sentences", or even "sentences" in any possible way here, I care about finding the maximum shared regions between two images and SO screenshots were the quickest illustration. The diff you show highlights the wrong thing for that: it's highlighting all the local differences, when instead it needs to highlight entire regions that match between the two images.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I couldn't produce the exact desired result but through a fairly blunt algorithm, I got somewhat close.  The general algorithm is:

1. **Add the same random noise to each image.**

   See the first and third pane in figure 1.  Adding the same noise to both images ensures that featureless regions (e.g. white background) can be compared via a phase correlation (below).
2. **Populate a matrix of zeros with a boxed subsection from image 1**

An example of this matrix is given in the middle pane of figure 1. This image must be the same dimensions as image 1 and image 2.

3. **Perform a phase correlation between the matrix from step two and the noisy image 2.**

There are several knobs that you can turn here that can improve the end result.  See [Performing a phase correlation with fft in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30630632/performing-a-phase-correlation-with-fft-in-r)

[image]

4. **Extract the x and y valued 'shifts' associated with the highest correlation value**

These values indicate how the matrix from step 2 should be shifted in the x and y directions so that the it best *matches* the noisy image 2.

5. **Adjust the position of the boxed subsection in step 3 so that all areas in the noisy image 1 are looped over.  Then repeat steps 3 and 4.**

This is done by looping over the rows and columns in image 1.  You can loop over every index or skip several indices.

6. **Create a matrix of the x and y shifts and plot to observe how the regions in image1 compare to image 2.**

[image]

Notice that the result is not exactly what you're looking for but its close.  Basically the red regions indicate that the corresponding regions in image 1 don't have to be shifted.  Yellow regions (in this case) need to be shifted slightly down, orange more so, and white need to be shifted the up.

Again, adding the same noise to image 1 and 2 is an important step.  The algorithm depends on isolating small boxed regions (in the example code, I used 50x50 pixel boxes).  As you loop through the rows and columns of image 1 and isolate corresponding boxed regions, several areas would contain regions with no features.  This poses problems in the phase correlation as a boxed featureless region will have multiple high correlation values in all regions that have a similar featureless background.  Effectively, adding noise adds features to both images in order to reduce ambiguous phase correlations.

The reasons this algorithm doesn't produce the same result as the desired is because the boxed regions aren't chosen in a clever way -- they are selected as you loop over the rows and columns of image 1.  Therefore, depending on the box size you choose, some boxed regions will have features that are translated differently when compared to image 2.  **Perhaps this algorithm would work better after the region clustering algorithm proposed by yapws87**

Here is the R code to produce these results:

```
## read in the images 
img1 <- readJPEG('./img1.jpg')
img2 <- readJPEG('./img2.jpg')

## grayscale the images
img1 <- (img1[,,1]+img1[,,2]+img1[,,3])/3
img2 <- (img2[,,1]+img2[,,2]+img2[,,3])/3


## rotate the images for more intuitive R plotting
img1 <- t(apply(img1,2,rev))
img2 <- t(apply(img2,2,rev))

## create some uniform noise 
noise <- matrix(runif(n=nrow(img1)*ncol(img1)),nrow=nrow(img1),ncol=ncol(img1))*0.1

## add the SAME noise to both images
img1 <- noise+img1
img2 <- noise+img2

## remove the mean from both images (this may not be necessary) 
img1 <- img1/mean(img1)
img2 <- img2/mean(img2)

## Take the conjugate of the fft of the second image
IMG2c <- Conj(fft(img2))

## define how to loop through the first image
row.step=50
col.step=50

## create a zero image (made with all 0s)
zero.img <- matrix(0,ncol=ncol(img1),nrow=nrow(img1))

## initialize some vectors to hold the x and y
## shifts that correspond to the highest phase correlation value
shift.x.vec=NULL
shift.y.vec=NULL

## keep track of how many iterations you go through
i.iters=1

## loop over the columns
i=1
while((i+col.step-1)<nrow(img1)) {

    ## keep track of how many iterations you go through
    j.iters=1

    ## loop over the rows
    j=1
    while((j+col.step-1)<ncol(img1)) {

        ## define a current 'box' as the zero image
        cbox1 <- zero.img

        ## then populate a small box with values from image 1
        cbox1[i:(i+row.step-1),j:(j+col.step-1)] <- img1[i:(i+row.step-1),j:(j+col.step-1)]

        ## PERFORM THE PHASE CORRELATION

        ## go into the frequency domain
        CBOX1 <- fft(cbox1)

        ## find a normalized value
        norm <- abs(CBOX1 * IMG2c)

        ## perform the phase correlation and go back to the space domain
        corr <- Re(fft((CBOX1 * IMG2c)/norm,inv=TRUE)/length(CBOX1))

        ## this rearranges the quadrants of the matrix see
        ## matlabs function fftshift
        corr <- fftshift(corr)

        ## find the x and y index values associated with the
        ## highest correlation value.
        shift <- which(corr==max(corr),arr.ind=TRUE)
        shift.x <- shift[1]
        shift.y <- shift[2]

        ## populate the x and y shift vectors
        shift.x.vec <- c(shift.x.vec,shift.x)
        shift.y.vec <- c(shift.y.vec,shift.y)

        ## THIS IS ADDITIONAL PLOTTING AND CAN BE IGNORED
        if(i.iters==6 & j.iters==6) {
            dev.new()
            ##jpeg('./example.jpeg',width=900,height=700)
            split.screen(c(1,3))
            screen(1)
            image(1:nrow(img1),1:ncol(img1),img1,col=gray.colors(200),axes=FALSE,ylab="",xlab="",useRaster=TRUE,main='Noisy Image 1')
            rect(j,i,(j+col.step-1),(i+row.step-1))

            screen(2)
            image(cbox1,col=gray.colors(200),axes=FALSE,useRaster=TRUE,main='Current Box')

            screen(3)
            image(img2,col=gray.colors(200),axes=FALSE,useRaster=TRUE,main='Noisy Image 2')

            ##dev.off()
        }

            
            
                
        j.iters=j.iters+1
        j=j+row.step
    }

    i.iters=i.iters+1
    i=i+col.step
        
}

## make a matrix of shifts values
## in this example, only the y shifts are interesting though
shift.x.mat <- matrix(shift.x.vec,ncol=j.iters-1,nrow=i.iters-1,byrow=TRUE)
shift.y.mat <- matrix(shift.y.vec,ncol=j.iters-1,nrow=i.iters-1,byrow=TRUE)


##jpeg('./final.jpeg',width=800,height=800)
image(shift.y.mat,axes=FALSE,useRaster=TRUE)
##dev.off()
```

Comment: Hm, why the noise, though?

Comment: Are you talking about the noise added to image 1 and 2 or the 'noise' in the final result?  Regardless, I addressed both these questions in two additional paragraphs after the final image and before the code that hopefully answers your question.

Comment: Hm, it feels like regions without features should be fine here, though: as long as we skip them as potential needles for finding correspondences, we can then grow any correspondence we find to include as many "empty" tiles as fit (we know the initial correspondence coordinates, comparing now known bounded regions is effectively when we finally _do_ want to pixel match, with some controlled tolerance).

Comment: This then reduces the source space as well as the target space, as we find and remove correspondence tiles until we're left with unmatched regions in the left image ("removals") and unmatched regions in the right image ("additions").

Comment: Interesting concept.  It would require a bit of finesse to determine which regions are featureless and then subsequently how to grow them but I like the idea in general.  Ill leave you (or another stacker) to the implementation but I am very curious as to how that would turn out!

Comment: I suspect it's going to be me... we'll see if I end up with enough motivation to start another library I may never finish =P

Comment: Yyyyep, took a while, but it very much turned out to be me. Self-answer posted.